# Error shows in vuetify components: Module build failed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, stylus

I am trying to build the vue application which shows these errors

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--12-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--12- 
2!./node_modules/stylus-loader??ref--12-3!./node_modules/vueti
fy/src/stylus/components/_lists.styl
Module build failed: /code/node_modules/stylus/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/opts-arg.js:7
  opts = { mode: 0o777, fs, ...opts }
                          ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/code/node_modules/stylus/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:1:79)
at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
@ ./node_modules/vuetify/src/stylus/components/_lists.styl 4:14-180 13:3-17:5 14:22-188
@ ./node_modules/vuetify/es5/components/VList/VList.js
@ ./node_modules/vuetify/es5/components/VList/index.js
@ ./node_modules/vuetify/es5/components/VSelect/VSelectList.js
@ ./node_modules/vuetify/es5/components/VSelect/VSelect.js
@ ./src/services/testAutoCompleteService.js
@ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js? 
  type=script&index=0!./src/pages/testPage.vue
@ ./src/pages/testPage.vue
@ ./src/router/index.js
@ ./src/main.js
```

Vue: 2.6.10

Vuetify: 1.5.11

OS: Linux

Node: 6.x

I tried to install the latest versions of the stylus and stylus-loader but nothing seems to be working.

Any webpack cofiguration needed to support the vuetify components?

Comment: It looks like Babel was not properly configured to handle the ES6 object destruction in `mkdirp` package used by `stylus`

Comment: How do we solve this issue?

Comment: The issue should not exist if you have created your project with Vue CLI and you had the Vuetify CLI plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-vuetify)

Comment: I investigated about mkdip package in stylus, i see it needs node version >10.x. I upgrade the latest node version and it is working fine.